# GameObject.Find isn't working correctly. How do I fix?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, object-reference

Okay so I have a simple fps maze game where you shoot targets to open doors to reach the end. When I shoot the second target it tells me that the reference isn't set to an instance of an object. (I have to use developer controls to get to the second target)

The first target is tagged "targ1" and the doorway is named "wall1". It should deactivate "wall1" but instead it deactivates "wall2". It works as intended in the unity editor, but not in the standalone app.

```
void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other) {

if (other.tag == "targ1")
    GameObject.Find("wall1").SetActive(false);

if (other.tag == "targ1x2"){
    GameObject.Find("wall1").SetActive(false);
    GameObject.Find("wall1").SetActive(false);
}   //In the build this is where the error is ^^
if (other.tag == "targ2")
    GameObject.Find("wall2").SetActive(false);

if (other.tag == "targ3")
    GameObject.Find("wall3").SetActive(false);

if (other.tag == "targ4")
    GameObject.Find("wall4").SetActive(false);

if (other.tag == "Finish")
    SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);       
}
```

I'm pulling my hair out over this. I've checked to make sure the tags and names were correct. Even completely deleted all my scenes and re did them, nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: When I shoot "targ1" it deletes "wall2", instead of the intended "wall1".

Comment: Why don't you detect the collision on each target instead of the bullet, and then in the target's script, disable it's associated wall (assigned in the inspector) when the bullet collides with it?

Comment: @MichaelCurtiss Wouldn't that take a separate script for each target type?
For instance each "target1" would have to have the specified script, and the same for every "target2"?

Comment: If all targets are doing the same thing, just disabling a gameobject when hit, or playing a sound or particle effect, they can all have the same Target script, and you would use the unity inspector to specify which gameobject to disable or which sound to play. If you need custom functionality, you can create subclasses of the Target class to implement it.

Comment: I tried this and I'm still having the same problem, maybe I'm troubleshooting the wrong thing.

Comment: Does your target script look like this?

`public class Target : MonoBehaviour{
 public GameObject wall;

 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other){
  if (other.tag != "bullet")
   return;

  wall.SetActive(false);
 }
}`

Make sure your bullet has tag 'bullet' and has a rigidbody and collider attached.

Comment: My target script ended up being basically identical, except for the names like "wall".

Comment: I got it, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so if anyone else is having this same, or similar issue, I found the answer to what was causing MY problem. It has nothing to do with my tedious way of coding, it has to do with Unity.
I had "wall1" inside of a prefab. In my prefab the name of the object was "wall1". So where in any instance of this prefab the object name would be defaulted to wall1.
 In order to stop this from happening you have to break the prefab instance, or the system will still believe its name to be the same as in the prefab. 
I guess this just goes to show that understanding the code isn't going to carry you, you have to understand your editor as well.